# jQuery value not being retained

Tags: jquery

I'm using a PouchDB database:

I am finding that -1 is what gets inserted in the `replace()` call.

But `console.log(result.total_rows);` shows `5` (which is what I expect).

Why isn't `totalRows` saving this value?

```
        var totalRows = -1;
        fDatabase.allDocs().then(function(result) {
            console.log(result);
            console.log(result.total_rows);
            totalRows = result.total_rows;
        }).catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        });

        var descriptionText = $('#description');

        // -1 is coming up here instead of 5???
       descriptionText.text(descriptionText.text().replace('__NUMBER__', totalRows));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the `allDocs`method is asynchronous, so your replace method will get executed before the query is completed and `totalRows` is updated with the correct count.

The solution is to place the update description code in the success callback.

```
var totalRows = -1;
fDatabase.allDocs().then(function (result) {
    console.log(result);
    console.log(result.total_rows);
    totalRows = result.total_rows;
    //since it is async need to place it in the callback
    var descriptionText = $('#description');
    // -1 is coming up here instead of 5???
    descriptionText.text(descriptionText.text().replace('__NUMBER__', totalRows));
}).
catch (function (error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: Thanks - that fixed it. I'll accept this answer in a few minutes when the timer expires. Out of interest (if you are familiar with PouchDB), if I want to retrieve each saved object do you know the best way I can do that? It seems `allDocs` just returns all of the _id's, not the actual data records.